# how to invoke a method in the scope using $timeout

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to use `$timeout` to invoke one function that I have, but I don't know how to invoke a function that is in the `$scope`. Let me exemplify

I have this:

```
$scope.play = function(){    
    // function implementation
    if(condition()){
        $timeout(play, 1000);
    }
}
```

it doesn't recognize the `play` function, I have also tried this

```
$timeout($scope.play, 1000);
```

and it also doesn't work. I had to work around it like this:

```
var play = function(){
    $scope.playInner();
}

$scope.playInner = function(){    
    // function implementation
    if(condition()){
        $timeout(play, 1000);
    }
}
```

But I'm sure there's a better way to do this, does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: My first thought is why aren't you using `$interval`?

Comment: are you injecting the $timeout service into your controller?

Comment: `$timeout($scope.play, 1000)` should work fine. Tell us how it didn't work. What happens?

Comment: Seems to work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/G2LHP/

Comment: Same here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CU7Xta6HvuHX4uzt7Vre?p=preview

Comment: This is so strange, it used to say that it couldn't identify $scope.play, although when I changed it back now it all worked as expected. Perhaps I missed something last time. Thank you all for your time. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @CaffGeek is `$interval` a better choice? I am new at AngularJS, I just found out about `$timeout` and was trying to make it work

Comment: I would think it is, since you are repeating a call until a given condition is false.  The documentation has a pretty good example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as JB Nizet suggested, `$timeout($scope.play, 1000)` should work fine.

**Example:**

```
function ctrl($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.data=0;
    $scope.play=function(){
        $scope.data++;
        $timeout($scope.play,1000);
    }    

}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/wF8SZ/